# Anova difference in SPSS and R

Tags: r, statistics, spss, anova

I'm quite new to R but I've tried recently to make a two way repeated measures ANOVA, to replicate the results that my supervisor did on SPSS.
I've struggled for days and read dozens of articles to understand what was going on in R, but I still don't get the same results.

```
    > mod <- lm(Y~A*B)
    > Anova(mod, type="III")
    Anova Table (Type III tests)

    Response: Y
                Sum Sq  Df F value    Pr(>F)    
    (Intercept)  0.000   1  0.0000   1.00000    
    A            2.403   5  8.6516 4.991e-08 ***
    B            0.403   2  3.6251   0.02702 *  
    A:B          1.220  10  2.1962   0.01615 *  
    Residuals   51.987 936  
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

My data are from a balanced design, I used the type III SS since it's the one used in SPSS as well. The Sum squares the Df, and the linear model are the same in SPSS, the only things that differ being the F and p value. Thus, it should not be a Sum square mistake.

Results in SPSS are:

```
              F    Sig.
    A     7.831   .000
    B     2.681   .073
    A:B   2.247   .014
```

I'm a little bit lost. Would it be a problem related to the contrasts?

Lucas

Comment: You should edit the code to include `library(car)`.  `lm` is usually called with a data argument. If you are using `attach` then a) STOP THAT, and b) post the output of `str()` on the data-object has Y, A and B.

Comment: You may want to post your SPSS syntax, as well.

Comment: I don't have the SPSS analysis, just the results!
I've also included the library(car) in the code, I just didn't show it. The Y is a vector with every data and the A & B the factors. I thought I would not need to call a data argument in that case..